# Swift Audio Recorder

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, audio-recording

Hi I am creating an audio recorder. I have few questions
Following is my deleting audio file snippet.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let path = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Recording\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        do{

            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: path)
            myTableView.reloadData()
        } catch{
            displayAlert(title: "OOPS", message: "Delete failed")
        }

}
```

when i delete the file is still displayed in the table view but i am not able to play it. so i guess it is getting deleted from the directory but not from the table view. so i used 
    myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic )

but it is crashing the application... when i search online people are creating arrays and deleting the audio from that. should i create array or can i delete with the URL itself

q2. in the tableview the audio file names are listed as 1, 2, 3 etc. but i want the name to be Recording1, Recording2 etc. with the file name given the file is created with word "Recording" in document directory but not in table view.. how to give correct name?

following is my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!
var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
var noOfRecords: Int = 0
@IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
@IBAction func recordPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if audioRecorder == nil{

        noOfRecords += 1
        let fileName =   getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Recording\(noOfRecords).m4a")
        print(fileName)
        let settings = [AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC), AVSampleRateKey: 12000, AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue]

        do{
            //record the audio
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: fileName, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.record()
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            recordButton.setTitle("Stop Recording", for: .normal)

        }catch{
            displayAlert(title: "OOPS", message: "Recording failed")
        }
    } else {
            audioRecorder.stop()
            audioRecorder = nil
            recordButton.setTitle("Start Recording", for: .normal)
        //store the last no for naming
            UserDefaults.standard.set(noOfRecords, forKey: "myNumber")
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Ask permission for Mic
    recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission { (hasPermission) in
        if hasPermission { print("Accepted")}

        //storing numbering logic
        if let number = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myNumber") as? Int
        { self.noOfRecords = number }

    }
}
//func to give path(URL) to store the recording
func getDirectory() -> URL {
    let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let docDirectory = path[0]
    return docDirectory
}

//func to display Alert
func displayAlert(title: String, message: String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

//setting up table View
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return noOfRecords
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row + 1)
    return cell
}

// listen to recorded audio
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let path = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Recording\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")
    print(path)
    do{
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path)
    audioPlayer.play()
    } catch{
        displayAlert(title: "OOPS", message: "Playback failed")
    }
}
// to delete the recording

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let path = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Recording\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        do{

            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: path)
            myTableView.reloadData()
        } catch{
            displayAlert(title: "OOPS", message: "Delete failed")
        }

}
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**swift 4**]  Following code is working for me. Use **tableView.deleteRows**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let path = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Recording\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        do{
            print("test", indexPath)
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: path)
             noOfRecords -= 1
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(noOfRecords, forKey: "myNumber")
        } catch{
            displayAlert(title: "OOPS", message: "Delete failed")
        }
    }
}
```

For the 2nd problem, use file name from document folder and show like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let path = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("Recording\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")
    let fileName = URL(fileURLWithPath: path.absoluteString).deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = fileName
    return cell
}
```